# R Studio is not launching after installation

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a problem with launching R Studio after installation, I have been using R for 2 years already in my job, but now I have a new computer and wanted to install R and RStudio. R version: 4.1.2 RStudio regardless version getting error. On my older Windows notebook, everything works fine. This is the first time I see something like this - it is a brand new pc 64-bit version. R normal GUI works also without problems, however, once RStudio launched getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Please consult the RStudio support. (Do you have a working R installation? Have you tested that by launching Rgui?)

Comment: Yes, R is working and I tested in Rgui - but for RStudio - the support response may take weeks and I have only 5 days. Then I will take the new pc with better stats or I will go with the old one. I have to return one of them.

Comment: Well, I would try setting a HOME path: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f